# passport-socketio breaks passport implementation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, passport.js, passport.socketio

This is my socket config:

```
// set authorization for socket.io
    io.set('authorization', passportSocketIo.authorize({
        cookieParser: express.cookieParser,
        key:         'connect.sid',       // the name of the cookie where express/connect stores its session_id
        secret:      '1234',    // the session_secret to parse the cookie
        store:       sessionStore,        // we NEED to use a sessionstore. no memorystore please
        success: function (data, accept) {
            console.log('successful connection to socket.io');

            // The accept-callback still allows us to decide whether to
            // accept the connection or not.
            accept(null, true);
        },
        fail: function (data, message, error, accept) {
            if(error)
                throw new Error(message);
            console.log('failed connection to socket.io:', message);

            // We use this callback to log all of our failed connections.
            accept(null, false);
        }
    }));
```

This is the passport implementation of login, which works great without passport.socketio:

```
exports.facebookStrategy = function () {

    return new FacebookStrategy({
        //client configuration
    },
    function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
        User.findOrCreate({uid: profile.id},
            {
                username: profile.username,
                gender: profile.gender,
                first_name: profile.name.givenName,
                last_name: profile.name.familyName,
                photo: 'https://graph.facebook.com/' + profile.username + '/picture?type=large',
                access_token: accessToken
            },
            function(err, user) {
                if (err) { return done(err); }
                done(null, user); // This is were it breaks
        });
        console.log(profile);
    });

}
```

This is the error I receive, and I have no idea how to solve it:

```
TypeError: object is not a function
    at pass (node_modules/passport/lib/passport/index.js:287:14)
    at Passport.serializeUser (/node_modules/passport/lib/passport/index.js:289:5)
    at IncomingMessage.req.login.req.logIn (node_modules/passport.socketio/node_modules/passport/lib/http/request.js:48:29)
    at Context.delegate.success (node_modules/passport/lib/passport/middleware/authenticate.js:194:13)
    at Context.actions.success (node_modules/passport/lib/passport/context/http/actions.js:21:25)
    at verified (/sociable/node_modules/passport-facebook/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:181:18)
    at /app/lib/auth.js:25:5
    at Promise.<anonymous> (/node_modules/mongoose-findorcreate/index.js:31:11)
    at Promise.<anonymous> (node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:177:8)
    at Promise.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
```

Why does it want to run some kind of function on the user object? I dont understand! If I leave the done method empty it won't crash but also no session is set and I am not logged in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**update:**
just make sure to use the same version of passport as the passport-socketio module is using, currently this is version 0.2.0, you might have to upgrade your passport-facebook module as well

**old post:**

I had the same problem and solved this by changing the passport-socket.io index.js file:

```
var defaults = {
passport:     require('passport'),
key:          'connect.sid',
secret:       null,
store:        null,
success:      function(data, accept){accept(null, true)},
fail:         function(data, message, critical, accept){accept(null, false)}
```

};

change this default configuration to:

```
var defaults = {
passport:     null,
key:          'connect.sid',
secret:       null,
store:        null,
success:      function(data, accept){accept(null, true)},
fail:         function(data, message, critical, accept){accept(null, false)}
```

};

Of course, this will only work if you pass in your own passport object like you are currently doing. 
The problem has something to do with passport-socketio requiring the passport module which overwrites the req.login function, I'll have a better look tomorrow to figure out exactly what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

pass passport var to passport-socketio object will solve this problem.

```
 io.set('authorization', passportSocketIo.authorize({
                passport: passport, //use passport
                cookieParser: express.cookieParser,
                key:         'connect.sid',       // the name of the cookie where express/connect stores its session_id
                secret:      '1234',    // the session_secret to parse the cookie
                store:       sessionStore,        // we NEED to use a sessionstore. no memorystore please
                success: function (data, accept) {
                    console.log('successful connection to socket.io');

                    // The accept-callback still allows us to decide whether to
                    // accept the connection or not.
                    accept(null, true);
                },
                fail: function (data, message, error, accept) {
                    if(error)
                        throw new Error(message);
                    console.log('failed connection to socket.io:', message);

                    // We use this callback to log all of our failed connections.
                    accept(null, false);
                }
            }));
```

Comment: Actually, it don't solve the problem. And why should it solve the problem? Could you maybe elaborate? I still receive the same error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: actually passport-socketio use old version of passport if we set passport in it's configuration then passport-socketio automatically set dependency.

Comment: It defaults to require('passport') so why would it use an old version of passport? Anyway, the same error message stays when I tried that.