# How to open a socket connection when a user is authorized to be added to the session?

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, passport.js, passport.socketio

I am attempting to set up an express server where a socket connection will be initiated upon user authentication using passport-local. I have been getting the error "TypeError: object is not a function" on the final line in the file that I configure my passport in.

This is my passport.js file:

```
var LocalStrategy   = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var Player          = require('../app/models/playerModel.js');

module.exports = function(passport) {
passport.serializeUser(function(player, done) {
    done(null, player.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    Player.findById(id, function(err, player) {
        done(err, player);
    });
});

//login
passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField : 'username',
    passwordField : 'password',
    passReqToCallback : true 
},
function(req, username, password, done) { // callback with username and password from our form

    // find a user whose username is the same as the forms username
    // we are checking to see if the user trying to login already exists
    Player.findOne({ 'local.username' :  username }, function(err, player) {
        // if there are any errors, return the error before anything else
        if (err)
            return done('test' + err);

        // if no user is found, return the message
        if (!player)
            return done(null, false, console.log('No user found.'));

    // if the user is found but the password is wrong
        if (!player.validPassword(password))
            return done(null, false, console.log('Oops! Wrong password.')); 

        // THIS IS THE LINE THAT THROWS THE ERROR
        return done(null, player);
    });

}));
};
```

Here is my server.js file:

```
var
 express  = require('express'), // framework
 http     = require('http'),
 io = require('socket.io'),
 mongoose = require('mongoose'), // object modeling for mongodb
 passport = require('passport'), // user authentication and authorization
 passportSocketIo = require('passport.socketio'),
 routes   = require('./app/routes.js'),
 configDB = require('./config/database.js'),
 MemoryStore = express.session.MemoryStore,
 sessionStore = new MemoryStore(),

 app      = express(),
 server   = http.createServer(app),
 port     = process.env.PORT || 8080;

mongoose.connect(configDB.url); // connect to our database

require('./config/passport')(passport); // pass passport for configuration

app.configure(function() {

// set up our express application
    app.use(express.logger('dev')); // log every request to the console
    app.use(express.cookieParser()); // read cookies (needed for auth)
    app.use(express.bodyParser()); // get information from html forms
    app.use(express.methodOverride()); // used for creating RESTful services
    app.use(express.static( __dirname + '/app')); // defines root directory for static files

// required for passport
    app.use(express.session({ secret: 'secret', key: 'express.sid' , store: sessionStore})); // session secret
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions
});

routes.configRoutes(app, server, passport); // load our routes and pass in our app and fully configured passport

server.listen(port);
io = io.listen(server);

io.set('authorization', passportSocketIo.authorize({
    cookieParser: express.cookieParser,
    key:         'express.sid',       // the name of the cookie where express/connect  stores its session_id
    secret:      'session_secret',    // the session_secret to parse the cookie
    store:       sessionStore,        
    success:     onAuthorizeSuccess,  // *optional* callback on success - read more below
    fail:        onAuthorizeFail,     // *optional* callback on fail/error - read more below
 }));

function onAuthorizeSuccess(data, accept){
  console.log('successful connection to socket.io');
  accept(null, true);
}

function onAuthorizeFail(data, message, error, accept){
  if(error)
    throw new Error(message);
  accept(null, false);
}
```

the part of my routes.js that handles login:

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
console.log("log in");
});

// process the login form
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
    successRedirect : '/', // redirect to the secure profile section
    failureRedirect : '/test', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
    failureFlash : true // allow flash messages
}));
```

If I comment out the io.set('authorization' function, the user seems to authenticate. I thought that all the function does is use the passport authentication function to allow a socket connection to be established. Why does it all of a sudden not authenticate when I attempt to start a socket connection?

I don't think I fully understand the way the authentication works. When I submit my login form, I send a post to "dirname/login", which is handled in my routes.js file. passport.authenticate is the callback to be run when the post is recieved, which then searches my db for the player and if the correct username and password is recieved the player object is serialized and added to the session. Where does socket.io come in? Does the io.set('authorization' function add a listener to see when the user is authenticated?

Sorry for the wall of code, I'm new to node and I don't fully understand the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22432210/passport-socketio-breaks-passport-implementation?rq=1)! Apparently, I just needed to change a line in my passport.socketio index.js file because socketio was trying to use a wierd version of passport.

Change This:

```
var defaults = {
   passport:     require('passport'),
   key:          'connect.sid',
   secret:       null,
   store:        null,
   success:      function(data, accept){accept(null, true)},
   fail:         function(data, message, critical, accept){accept(null, false)}
};
```

to this:

```
var defaults = {
   passport:     null,
   key:          'connect.sid',
   secret:       null,
   store:        null,
   success:      function(data, accept){accept(null, true)},
   fail:         function(data, message, critical, accept){accept(null, false)}
};
```

and then pass the passport obj you are using to the io authorization function:

```
io.set('authorization', passportSocketIo.authorize({
    passport:     passport,
    cookieParser: express.cookieParser,
    key:         'express.sid',       // the name of the cookie where express/connect  stores its session_id
    secret:      'session_secret',    // the session_secret to parse the cookie
    store:       sessionStore,        
    success:     onAuthorizeSuccess,  // *optional* callback on success - read more below
    fail:        onAuthorizeFail,     // *optional* callback on fail/error - read more below
}));
```